# JS function parameters are declared but never read

Tags: javascript, function, object, function-parameter

I have an input in html and want to put the text of the input into an object on JS and display it on a

tag on html as a result.
Because I didnt wanted to simplify the code, i tried to create a function (so that I can call it for each object attribute.
`<input type="text" placeholder="Typ" id="type-mhouse" />`
Is the input.

```
const land = {
  Type: "",
  Adress: "",
  Value: "",
  updateValue: function (x, y, z) {
    this.x = document.getElementById(y).value;
    document.getElementById(z).textContent = this.x;
    console.log(this[0]);
  },
};
```

Is the JS.

```
<p class="ergebnis" id="ergtype-house"></p>
```

Is where the result is displayed.

**The problem is:** when I type for example "Flat" in the input, it displays properly on the html output, but the land.Type remains "".

Ive tried everything and I'm still very new to JS so I cant solve it.
(Also I know that I shouldnt name stuff "Type" or "Value".. I'll change it.)

Thanks for any comment!

**IMPORTANT Edit:** The land object is used in a linked js file.
The function is called inside the HTML on a button click:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          
          //Button on Modal
          $("#submit").click(function () {
           
            land.updateValue("Type", "type-mhouse", "ergtype-house");

          });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: Where are you using `land` object?

Comment: In a separate script.js file, linked to the html. However the button that confirms the change is stored in a JSON script on the html

Comment: Please post the whole code.

Comment: @youngmago where are you changing the `land.Type` value? Please post your whole code for us to help.

Comment: Sorry, i edited it now and posted the code. Thanks for helping !

Comment: I added the JSON code, which is in the HTML as a script. The JS code is the full code (im still starting out). Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you try to do but here is a solution to fix your issues.

```
const land = {
  type: "",
  address: "",
  value: "",
  updateValue: function(landAttributeName, textElementId, displayElementId) {
    this[landAttributeName] = document.getElementById(textElementId).value;
    document.getElementById(displayElementId).innerText = this[landAttributeName] || '';
  },
};
```

BTW, you're right, you should use names more easily understandable  :-)

There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.
-- Phil Karlton

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and the quote! You saved me from more days of headache. It works!! I wanted to modify the object attributes with an input and display them on the page by button click.

Comment: Thanks again!! If you have the time could you explain to me in short what i did wrong?